# Is it possible to select vertices at runtime in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, selection, mesh

[image: screenshot from 3D modeling software]

Hello, I just want to add a function for selecting vertices at runtime. (drag and select)
Is there any way to do it? just like 3ds Max or Maya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll have to implement the logic yourself. However this will not be trivial, also due to the fact that Unity being a game engine is not designed to deal with large numbers of vertices.

Have a look at the [mesh documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html). There you can find out about vertex manipulation in unity.